# How to open Default Browser App dialog in my browser app

Tags: java, android, browser

I am new to android development and have an issue with one problem.

I want to show a Changing Default Browser App dialog to user. In that dialog all Browser Apps will be displayed and user can select one default browser app that he/she want to use.

So my question is, "How to open Default Browser App dialog in my browser app?"

Please see below attached screenshot of dialog for your reference.

[Default Dialog Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tjwDg.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Android >= Q use `RoleManager` with `ROLE_BROWSER` role.

For Android < Q and >= N navigate user to Android Default Apps Settings.

For Android < N open help page to show user how to change default app.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final String SETTINGS_SELECT_OPTION_KEY = ":settings:fragment_args_key";
    private static final String SETTINGS_SHOW_FRAGMENT_ARGS = ":settings:show_fragment_args";
    private static final String DEFAULT_BROWSER_APP_OPTION = "default_browser";

    private final ActivityResultLauncher<Intent> resultLauncher =
            registerForActivityResult(
                    new ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult(),
                    result -> {
                        if (result.getResultCode() == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Role is granted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        } else {
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Role is not granted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    }
            );

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
            RoleManager roleManager = (RoleManager) getSystemService(ROLE_SERVICE);
            Intent intent = roleManager.createRequestRoleIntent(RoleManager.ROLE_BROWSER);
            resultLauncher.launch(intent);
        } else if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_DEFAULT_APPS_SETTINGS);
            intent.putExtra(
                    SETTINGS_SELECT_OPTION_KEY,
                    DEFAULT_BROWSER_APP_OPTION
            );
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putString(SETTINGS_SELECT_OPTION_KEY, DEFAULT_BROWSER_APP_OPTION);
            intent.putExtra(
                    SETTINGS_SHOW_FRAGMENT_ARGS,
                    bundle
            );
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            startActivity(intent);
        } else {
            // Show some help page
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @shmakova shmakova for answering...
Can you please share working code snippet in JAVA language? It will be great help if you can. And one more question is your solution is for above Android 10+. Right? S what about below that? I want to cover all edges for making browser app as default. Thank you.

Comment: On Android 9 and below, there is no such window. You should navigate user to Android Default Apps Settings to change default browser

Comment: Thanks @shmakova shmakova Your answer is working perfectly for above Android 10+ (as you have mentioned). One small request, Can you please share code snippet for navigate user to Android Default Apps Settings to change default browser for below Android 9. Once again Thanks in Advance :)

Comment: I added, check please @PratikDhoriyani